# Add bounty to get canonical answer on already answered

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have already answered here and it was approved by the OP.

[Dynamically add columns in an existing table on the fly in CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362123/dynamically-add-columns-in-an-existing-table-on-the-fly-in-cakephp-3)

However, technically my own answer seemed slightly vague and I have been working on achieving results based on 'rules', what I provided was a hack-around and it seemed to work, just fine. The code I submitted was tested on basic hello world and applied the logic to see if the hack worked. However, that is the right way to do it (note my comments there) However, there is no other way to do it either.

I want this question to get more attention and maybe find a way to submit a PR to the original authors of the framework, thus the need of a canonical answer which is close to what could be submitted without breaking the architecture.

What I want is not a perfect answer - I checked here : [Ethics on Bounty Award when best answer only solved half of the problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267376/ethics-on-bounty-award-when-best-answer-only-solved-half-of-the-problem) .

Should I post a bounty of higher reps to gain more attention or should I start a new question asking for help? Or is it not right for stack-overflow or goes in Programmers stackexchange?

What I expect is:

- Half correct answer or full answer would be super-awesome!
- A way of awarding bounty even though OP accepted my own answer but I would like award bounty per this [Is it OK to accept one answer and award bounty to another?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319208/is-it-ok-to-accept-one-answer-and-award-bounty-to-another)
- The answer may or may not be canonical but atleast provides an insight to the direction.

Comment: If you're looking for another answer to the same question, you certainly shouldn't post it again. If you'd like to encourage more attention to the question in the hope of encouraging a better answer, then by all means add a bounty.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe . I only want to encourage more attention to the question.